# How to fix MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Exceptions.AmazonSqsConnectionException in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a dot net application running on `aws` ec2 instance as a `docker` container but it throws this error:

```
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Exceptions.AmazonSqsConnectionException: ReceiveTransport faulted: https://ap-southeast-2/ ---> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Failed to retrieve credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
   at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeValueFactory`1.CreateValue()
   at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeTracker`1.AddNode(INodeValueFactory`1 nodeValueFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveTransport`1.ReceiveTransportAgent.RunTransport()
   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveTransport`1.ReceiveTransportAgent.Run()
   at MassTransit.Transports.StartHostHandle.EndpointsReady(Task`1[] endpoints)
   at MassTransit.Transports.StartHostHandle.ReadyOrNot(Task`1[] endpoints, Task`1[] riders)
   at MassTransit.MassTransitBus.Handle.ReadyOrNot(Task`1 ready)
   at MassTransit.MassTransitBus.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.MassTransitBus.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at API.Infrastructure.MassTransitExtensions.MassTransitHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/API/Infrastructure/MessageBus.cs:line 35
```

And here's my `MessageBus.cs`

```
.
.
.
<retracted-code>

        public static IServiceCollection UseMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            return services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri($"amazonsqs://{Configuration["MessageBus:Transports:SQSSNS:Region"]}"), h =>
                    {
                        h.AccessKey(Configuration["MessageBus:Transports:SQSSNS:AccessKeyId"]);
                        h.SecretKey(Configuration["MessageBus:Transports:SQSSNS:SecretAccessKey"]);

                        // specify a scope for all queues
                        h.Scope(Configuration["MessageBus:Prefix"]);

                        // scope topics as well
                        h.EnableScopedTopics();
                    });

                    var sqsPrefix = Configuration["MessageBus:Prefix"].ToLower();
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{sqsPrefix}-messaging-service", e =>
                    {
                        // add common consumers
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{sqsPrefix}-messaging-service-email", e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer<BankStatementRequestEmailConsumer>(services.BuildServiceProvider());
                        e.Subscribe<BankStatementRequested>();
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{sqsPrefix}-messaging-service-sms", e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer<BankStatementRequestSMSConsumer>(services.BuildServiceProvider());
                        e.Subscribe<BankStatementRequested>();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: The OP solved the issue himself here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826093/failed-to-retrieve-credentials-from-ec2-instance-metadata-service?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng no this doesn't help thoug